# AngularJS 2 Observable - xhr fail redirect

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am currently writing a Angular 2 web app and I would like to create an 'interceptor' that detect if an xhr request has been denied because of `authorization (401)`.

If this happen I would like my application to redirected to the login page for example.

I am not sure how to proceed to have such behavior, any idea, best practice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the `<router-outlet>` is one approach, but I found the Auth0 example to have some flaws (and also causes Angular 2 to break if you use custom pipes with a custom router outlet due to a bug).

I found an alternative approach, proposed by [Brandon Roberts on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112), which is basically to use the `@CanActivate` decorator. The idea is to annotate your route components with the `@CanActivate` which contains the logic for whether the current user has access or not to a given route.

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {CanActivate} from 'angular2/router';
import {Page} from './Page';
import {isLoggedIn} from './is-logged-in';

@Component({
  ...
})
@CanActivate((next: ComponentInstruction, previous: ComponentInstruction) => {
  return isLoggedIn(next, previous);
})
export class Protected {
}
```

As you can see, `@CanActivate` takes a function with the previous `ComponentInstruction` and the next one you're about to transition to.

> [ComponentInstruction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/ComponentInstruction-class.html) is an object that represents the route data for a given component, frankly, the information about the previous and next route to be invoked.

Currently there's only one "problem" with it, which is that you cannot inject dependencies into the CanActivate function. That's why you have to apply a workaround, namely to store your injector (ideally the root injector) somewhere.

```
// app-injector.ts
import {Injector} from 'angular2/core';

let appInjectorRef: Injector;
export const appInjector = (injector?: Injector):Injector => {
    if (injector) {
      appInjectorRef = injector;
    }

    return appInjectorRef;
};
```

Then, in your `main.ts` file where the Angular 2 bootstrapping logic resides...

```
// main.ts
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
...
import {App} from './app';
import {appInjector} from './app-injector';

bootstrap(App, [
  ...
]).then((appRef: ComponentRef) => {
  // store a reference to the application injector
  appInjector(appRef.injector);
});
```

...you get that class pass the root injector to it. You can now get a reference to your injector from other places by simply importing it like

```
import {appInjector} from './app-injector';

let injector = appInjector();
let someDep = injector.get(...);
```

The nice side effect of this approach here is that it is much more visible and flexible. Extending the `<router-outlet>` is somehow hidden behind the scenes.

Anyways, you can find a live code example of the above in Brandon's Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/SF8gsYN1SvmUbkosHjqQ?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this example.
I was able to adjust it in order to somehow integrate this in my application. 

Now I am experiencing a bug that you can reproduce on the plunker which is the fact that the history state is pushed too many times by the /login. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You can easily reproduce it with the following steps :

Open the plunker in a new page.
Set the page as being a chrome tab (in order to see the history state).
Click on the login link (you will see that the history has 2 '/' state)
Click on the protected link (you will see that the history has '/login')
Click go back (nothing is happening, we are moving from /login to /login - this is the problem).
Click go back again (we are finally redirected to the home page).

Comment: I have been able to identify that the problem is coming from router.navigate that is adding twice the state in the history.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
export class CustomHTTPConnection implements Connection
{
}
```

Note that Connection is an Abstract class so you would have to build it out completely from scratch.

Another way would be to go the Auth0 way which is close to the same thing.  https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/master/angular2-jwt.ts and then you could add the handling of 401 errors there, and send them to your login page on a 401.

Or, you could put restrictions on all of your routes if the user is not logged in, and always redirect to login if they try and visit other parts of your website.

Make a new router-outlet, that acts like another one but does a check to see if they are logged in via activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction).  You could also add publicRoutes to say you can go to certain pages without being logged in.  **WARNING you can't do this, this way using HashLocationStrategy as it doesn't log this.parentRouter.lastNavigationAttempt correctly.

```
import {Directive, Attribute, ElementRef, DynamicComponentLoader} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouterOutlet, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';
import {Login} from '../login/login.component';

@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})
export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
  publicRoutes: any;
  private parentRouter: Router;

  constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
              _parentRouter: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string) {
    super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);

    this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
    this.publicRoutes = {
    };
  }

  activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
    var url = this.parentRouter.lastNavigationAttempt;
    console.log(url);
    if (!this.publicRoutes[url] && !localStorage.getItem('jwt')) {//Public Routes does not work with Hash Location Strategy, need to come up with something else.
      // todo: redirect to Login, may be there is a better way?
      this.parentRouter.navigate(['Login']);
    }
    return super.activate(instruction);
  }
}
```

Then just call it like you normally would:

```
import {LoggedInRouterOutlet} from './utility/LoggedInOutlets';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [LoggedInRouterOutlet],
    template: `<div class="container">
                   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
               </div>`
})
```

Now this will check if they are logged in every time they go to another route,  the cool thing about doing it this way is I don't have to ping the server every time, although unsafe and would not recommend in production, it can save you some time in development!

Answer (score 0):

An approach could be to extend the `HTTP` object to intercept errors:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('request...');
    return super.request(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });        
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('get...');
    return super.get(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });
  }
}
```

and register it as described below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    new Provider(Http, {
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  })
]);
```

If 401 errors occur as this level, you could redirect the user to login page based on the current router you injected on this `CustomHttp` class.

Comment: Thank you for this. This will definitely help.
I will try to inject my Auth service in this and see if the application is acting on it. I will keep you posted.